# phpMailer not working on iPage server - UCE strictly prohibited error

Tags: phpmailer

I'm trying to run a phpMailer function on my server (iPage) and I can't get it to work. I've tried to use gmail to make sure the script was fine and it's working perfectly. After spending more than 4 days troubleshooting with iPage live help and support ticket platform, I've decided to share my problem with you.

Here's the function I'm using :

```
  function send_mail($email,$message,$subject) {
    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.ipage.com";
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->AddCC('info@m7b5.com', 'm7b5');
    $mail->Username="test@m7b5.com";
    $mail->Password="dsdw23dds";
    $mail->SetFrom('info@m7b5.com','m7b5');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("info@m7b5.com","m7b5");
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
    }
  }
```

And now first lines of the error code :

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 ESMTP Sat, 04 Mar 2017 10:31:18 -0500: UCE strictly prohibited 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-bosauthsmtp10.yourhostingaccount.com Hello www.m7b5.com [66.96.143.93] 250-SIZE 34603008 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 TLS go ahead 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-bosauthsmtp10.yourhostingaccount.com Hello www.m7b5.com [66.96.143.93] 250-SIZE 34603008 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK id=1ckBeS-0001xZ-SM
```

Ever faced the UCE strictly prohibited error? 
Any workarounds I could use to resolve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Un, that's not an error, it's just a welcome banner. Most commercial mail services say something like that, but it has no technical meaning.  Post the rest of the SMTP transcript and we will be able to see the real problem.

Comment: That's interesting. I was sure that the UCE message was the error causing the email not to pass through. I've edited my post with more lines from the SMTP Debug. I hope you'll be able to see something wrong in there but at first sight nothing seems problematic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Indeed - it shows a successful delivery. Whatever problem you've got, it's not at this stage.